# Capture both of two optional groups

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture the word preceding the sequence `' AE'` (if any) or the word preceding the sequence `' BE'` (again, if any), or both words if both sequences appear in a string.

I tried with the following regular expression:

```
TEST = re.compile(
    r'(.*?)'
    r'(?:(\w+) AE)?'
    r'.*?'
    r'(?:(\w+) BE)?')
```

It captures either a word preceding `' BE'` or a word preceding `' AE'` but not
both words.

```
>>> TEST.match('').groups()
('', None, None)
>>> TEST.match('foo AE').groups()
('', 'foo', None)
>>> TEST.match('foo BE').groups()
('', None, 'foo')
>>> TEST.match('foo AE bar BE').groups()
('', 'foo', None)
```

Instead I would like the last line of output be

```
>>> TEST.match('foo AE bar BE').groups()
('', 'foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: `re.findall` would be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`RegexObject.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall):

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(.*?)\s*(?:AE|BE)')
>>>
>>> pattern.findall('')
[]
>>> pattern.findall('bar BE')
['bar']
>>> pattern.findall('foo AE')
['foo']
>>> pattern.findall('foo AE bar BE')
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Compiling the pattern is usually unnecessary.  From the docs "The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.match()`, `re.search()` or `re.compile()` are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions."

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Thank you for comment. I just don't wanted to repeat the same pattern multiple times in the answer, and wanted to keep OP's code style.

Comment: Not ideal because when only one group matches I don't know which one it is (AE or BE?).

Comment: @ErnestA, Try `pattern = re.compile(r'\s*(.*?)\s*(AE|BE)'); pattern.findall('foo AE bar BE')` => `[('foo', 'AE'), ('bar', 'BE')]`